# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function such that $f(0)=0 \text{ and } f(1)=1 \text{ and } \mid f'(x)\,\mid\,\leq 2\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$ If a and b are real numbers such that the set of all possible values of $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx$ is the open interval $(a,b).$ Then find $(b-a).$

Comment: There's only one value of $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$. What do you mean by "the set of all possible values"?

Comment: @Cauchy I think that $f(x)$ can be different.

Comment: @Ixion different from what?!

Comment: @Cauchy sorry, my english isn't so good... I mean that $f(x)$ can change.

Comment: @Cauchy in the original post it was a "less than or equal to" sign. If the OP says otherwise I will change it.

Comment: @Ixion but that wouldn't make sense. $f$ is a given function

Comment: For each such $f$ you get a value of the integral.  The set of all possible values (one for each $f$) is the intent of the question.

Comment: @Dave never mind, I miscomputed anyway.

Comment: I read the question as (maybe) asking: look at the convex set of all differentiable $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ for which $|f'|\le2$ on $[0,1],\space f(0)=0,$ and $f(1)=1.$  What is the image of that set under $f\mapsto \int_0^1 f ?$  (Which is what I think GEdgar just said.)

Comment: I see you did not like my edit. You should know your title is not very good as it conveys almost nothing. The body of the question as you have it is quite confusing. If anyone cares, here's the title I chose: "Range of $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ for $f$ satisfying certain conditions" I rephrased the body of the question as "Let $X$ be the set of all differentiable functions on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0, f(1)=1,$ with $|f'(x)|\le 2$ for all $x\in \mathbb R.$ What is the range of the function $I:X\to \mathbb R$ given by $I(f) = \int_0^1f(x)\,dx?$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the upper bound.

Since $f'(x) \le 2$ and $f(0) = 0$, for all $x \in (0,1)$ we have $f(x) \le 2x$.  Since $f'(x) \ge -2$ and $f(1)=1$, for all $x \in (0,1)$ we have $f(x) \le 3-2x$.  Therefore
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx \le \int_0^{3/4} 2x\,dx + \int_{3/4}^1 (3-2x)\,dx = \frac{7}{8}.
$$

I will leave the lower bound to you.

**added**
Why is $f(x) \le 3-2x$?  Here:

$$
f(1) - f(x) = \int_x^1 f'(x)\,dx \ge \int_x^1 (-2)\,dx
\\
1-f(x) \ge (-2)\cdot(1-x)
\\
3-2x \ge f(x)
$$

**added**
(a remark of zhw that $f'$ need not be Riemann integrable)
So, we use the mean value theorem.  Since $f$ is differentiable, it is also continuous.  So
$$
\frac{f(1)-f(x)}{1-x} = f'(\xi) \ge -2
$$
for some point $\xi$ between $x$ and $1$.  Same reasoning for $f(x)-f(0)$ to get the $2x$ bound.

Comment: A remark on how that bound cannot be obtained, and why $7/8$ is sharp, would be a nice addition.

Comment: Some clueless soul downvoted this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your solution (I don't downvote it). why $f(x)\le 3-2x$?

Comment: I can understand the downvote.  I didn't wait for Vibe to come back and answer the questions in the comments.

Comment: @Ixion Find the line of slope $-2$ through $(1,1).$

Comment: @GEdgar Now I get the beautiful solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: @GEdgar I deleted my comment... I  don't know what idea I had in mind!

Comment: Since $f'$ need not be Riemann integrable, why not refer to the line of slope $-2$ through $(1,1)?$

Comment: No, that's false, as the Pompeiu example shows.

Comment: @GEdgar is the lower bound 1/4?

Comment: @Vibe I'm pretty sure it's $1/8.$

Comment: @zhw Yeah it's 1/8 , had done mistake in integrating